# click_no_wait doesn`t act click

Tags: ruby, watir, web-testing

I have some code like this:

```
    content.button(:id,/Submit/).click_no_wait
    puts 2
    autoit = WIN32OLE.new("AutoItX3.Control")
    puts 3
    autoit.WinWait "XXXX"
    puts 4
    autoit.ControlClick "","OK","Button1"
```

After click the Submit button,a alert box will pop out,and the code after will click OK of that.The function "click" will hang program there so I need to use "click_no_wait".

But as a result,I can get the puts of 3,and the submit button doesn`t been licked.

Why?And what is the best solution?

Comment: It looks like your element is in a frame, which has a bug when using click_no_wait. A [newer question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13918184/1200545) has a workaround.

Comment: Hadn`t that been fixed?http://jira.openqa.org/browse/WTR-459

Comment: When I was looking at the code, the comments in another method suggested that the method was broken by changes in Ruby 1.9 (ie the bug was re-introduced).

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with javascript popups, see this page: http://watirwebdriver.com/javascript-dialogs/

Comment: I have read that page,the method "browser.alert.ok
" should be used after alert box pop out,right?So the click_no_wait also need to click.
And the method to run js leads me to another problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13698335/ole-error-code-80020101-caused-by-execute-script-of-waitr#comment18827428_13698335
would you please see that one?Thanks,and I will accept your answer if there is no better one.

Answer (score 0):

If the `#click_no_wait` does not open the dialog, but regular `#click` will, then it does not work for some reason. I have written a blog post about debugging `#click_no_wait` problems at http://itreallymatters.net/post/1366392123/debugging-and-improving-watirs-click-no-wait-method#.UMCuJoOgnvA

In short, set `$DEBUG` to `true` before `#click_no_wait` to get more troubleshooting information:

```
$DEBUG=true
content.button(:id,/Submit/).click_no_wait
$DEBUG=false
```

Comment: I got the error below,and that bug link seems not concern:
Exception 'NoMethodError' at h:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3
.2.0/lib/watir-classic/locator.rb:124 - unknown property or method: 'type'
    HRESULT error code:0x80020006
      Unknown name.

Comment: Make your test script to wait forever, for example with loop do sleep 1 end after #click_no_wait and then open up a separate terminal window and enter the outputted click_no_wait command manually after you've removed the linebreaks. What do you see?

Comment: sorry,is that you mean go into the output of click_no_wait?How?

Comment: I meant the output when $DEBUG was set to true, the command itself and the result of that command.

Comment: I did what you said the your answer,and the output is several pages of the same error which have mentioned in my first comment to your answer,after that is "#no_wait command:
ruby -e "$:.unshift........(a lot of address,too long for a comment);require 'h:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.3.0/lib/watir-classic/core';Watir::Button.new(Watir::IE.attach(:hwnd, 1382974).frame({:tag_name=>['frame', 'iframe'], :name=>/content/}), :tag_name => Array.new << 'button' << 'submit' << 'image' << 'reset', :unique_number => 2).click!();""   Do you need this?Or I haven`t catch you?