# OLE error code 80020101 caused by execute_script of waitr

Tags: watir, ole

I just tried this:`$browser.execute_script("alert(\"aaa\")")`

and then I get the error below:

```
h:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.2.0/lib/watir-classic/page-container.rb:46:in `method_missing': (in OLE method `execScript': ) (WIN32OLERuntimeError)
OLE error code:80020101 in <Unknown>
  Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.HRESULT error code:0x80020009
  Exception occurred.
    from h:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.2.0/lib/watir-classic/page-container.rb:46:in `rescue in execute_script'
    from h:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.2.0/lib/watir-classic/page-container.rb:39:in `execute_script'
```

Am I missing install something?

Comment: My understanding is that this means there is a javascript error on the page. Are you trying the code on an actual page? I do not believe it works on the "about:blank" page?

Comment: Yes this is on an actual page,I just write that for short.

Comment: Did you check if a javascript error has occurred when you run the code?

Comment: Oh that`s the reason!I goto a page with no error and my script acts!
But js always goes wrong for browser compatibility or something.Can I just ignore that?

Answer (score 1):

The exception means that a javascript error occurred when running the script.

While it would be better to fix the script, but if you really want to ignore the exception, you could wrap it in a begin-rescue:

```
begin
    $browser.execute_script("asdfasd") 
rescue WIN32OLERuntimeError
    #Ignore javascript error that occurred
end
```

When the exception occurs, the rescue will catch it and allow the program to continue.

Comment: Oh...that doesn`t work.It seems that before the script be executed the exception has already be threw.I got nothing here although program continues...

Answer (score 0):

Try if single quotes make it work:

```
$browser.execute_script("alert('aaa')")
```

Comment: So, try just $browser.execute_script("var a=1"). Does it still blow up? Does it work if you open up about:blank in your browser? If that's the case, then as Justin pointed out, something is causing JS errors on your page, maybe even unrelated with execute_script.

Comment: Yes;No;Do you mean execute_script can NOT run js if the page has js error itself?

Comment: I'm not aware of such a limitation by IE itself (e.g. it is not a limitation of execute_script, because it will just call IE OLE API, which throws that error). As i understand then you also got an error on "about:blank"? Both of b.execute_script("var a=1") and b.execute_script("alert('aaa')") worked for me as expected. That suggests that you might have some IE specific problems. I don't have any other ideas than to suggest you to change some security settings and see if that helps.

Comment: Sorry,my mistake,the JS error is just occur by the execute_script,and  it is "SCRIPT1014: Invalid character" from "json2.js, line 1 character 1" at "watir-classic-3.3.0\lib\watir-classic\ext".After several test,I found that when I open a page if the document mode of IE is IE7 there will comes this error,and so do the OLE error,everything will work fine when document mode is IE9.